# How to specify perticular table columns case sensitive in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
 String dmlString="INSERT INTO table VALUES('Rxyz');
 SqlCommand comObj = new SqlCommand(dmlString, conObj);
                comObj.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

table -> Rxyz

How to validate it, as Rxyz (case sensitive)

Comment: What do you mean, "validate it"? Against what? Are you trying to ensure that the column is unique and that you can store `Rxyz` and `RXYZ` and they are still unique? Are you trying to ensure that if someone says `WHERE column = 'RXYZ'` they get 0 rows? Please be specific about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 7):

You can specify the collation of the column as case-sensitive, e.g.

```
create table tbl (
str varchar(10) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
)
```

Example

```
insert tbl select 'Rxyz';
select * from tbl where str = 'rxyz';
select * from tbl where str = 'Rxyz';

Results

str
----------

(0 row(s) affected)

str
----------
Rxyz

(1 row(s) affected)
```

However, use care when joining this table column to other tables that are case-insensitive.  You will need to specifically add COLLATE clauses to the column comparisons.

Comment: +1 for guessing - this would have been one of my answer choices but I am having a hard time interpreting the actual requirement here.

Comment: I read the title only, easier for this question :) *(no, not really)*